# Have d3js respond to touch on mobile devices

Tags: mobile, d3.js

I've got a D3 app which uses `force` to display nodes and links.  On my PC, the nodes respond to touch, but on my iPhone, they do not.

My code isn't open source (yet?), but in researching, I noticed [this example](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html) *also* doesn't work on my iPhone like it does on my computer:

http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111116/force-collapsible.html

On the phone, I can drag the nodes; I can zoom in on the graph..  but if I tap the light blue circles, they don't become big blue circles as they do on my PC.

Using [Chrome device mode](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/device-mode), I tested several different emulated devices.  Of the mobile devices, only the Nokia devices worked.

How can I get d3 nodes to respond to touch on mobile devices?

Comment: D3 supports touches event and using this u can get touch position coordinates, check:  https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#d3_touches